# Convert 2 successive Bytes to one int value Increase speed in C#

Tags: c#, performance, byte

I need to combine two Bytes into one int value.

I receive from my camera a 16bit Image were two successive bytes have the intensity value of one pixel. My goal is to combine these two bytes into one "int" vale.

I manage to do this using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VectorLength * 2; i = i + 2)
{
  NewImageVector[ImagePointer] = ((int)(buffer.Array[i + 1]) << 8) | ((int)(buffer.Array[i]));      
  ImagePointer++;
}
```

My image is 1280*960 so VectorLength==1228800 and the incomming buffer size is   2*1228800=2457600 elements...

Is there any way that I can speed this up?
Maybe there is another way so I don't need to use a for-loop.

Thank you

Comment: .NET 4.5 has a `BitConverter` class that might be useful -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Comment: @nevada_scout `BitConverter` does the same thing but with additional checks, which probably makes it slower. -- It does use unsafe pointer to access the array elements however, which is the optimization OP can do here.

Comment: Am I correct  when I say that you want to transform every two byte pair into a short (not an int)? So buffer[0] and buffer[1] should go into NewImageVector[0], buffer[2] and buffer[3] into NewImageVector[1] (etc.etc.)? If so, [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) might be your friend.

Comment: Willem Yes you are correct. I know what Buffer.BlockCopy does, but how can I edit it to do what I want here? any suggestion?

Comment: @Spyros: I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can (re-)define `NewImageVector` as a `short[]`, and every two consecutive bytes in `Buffer` should be transformed into a `short` (which basically what you're doing now, only you cast to an `int` afterwards), you can use [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to do it for you.

As the documentation tells, you `Buffer.BlockCopy` copies bytes from one array to another, so in order to copy your bytes in buffer you need to do the following:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(Buffer, 0, NewImageVector, 0, [NumberOfExpectedShorts] * 2)
```

This tells `BlockCopy` that you want to start copying bytes from `Buffer`, starting at index 0, to `NewImageVector` starting at index 0, and you want to copy `[NumberOfExpectedShorts] * 2` bytes (since every short is two bytes long).

No loops, but it does depend on the ability of using a `short[]` array instead of an `int[]` array (and indeed, on using an array to begin with).

Note that this also requires the bytes in `Buffer` to be in `little-endian` order (i.e. `Buffer[index]` contains the low byte, `buffer[index + 1]` the high byte).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but will this not give me again a short[] array of 2457600 elements?? My point is that I want to make the 2457600  element array to  1228800 element array...

Comment: This is by far the fastest option out of those presented.

Comment: @Spyros: Nope. BlockCopy copies bytes. your short[] array with 1228800 elements contains  2457600 bytes. Which is exactly what will get copied. And afterwards you end up with 1228800 shorts (of 2 bytes each, making 2457600 bytes).

Comment: ok I will try it and let you know in a few minutes. Thank you

Comment: FWIW: The debug version of this runs in 2ms on my machine ;) / 4200 ticks in a release build.

Comment: Ok this escalate things. Your suggestion works on 1ms on my machine. Thank you very much. As @odyss-jii suggested this is by far the fastest route! Many many thanks!!!

Comment: One last thing. This solution makes short_value=Byte1 & Byte2 but what is i want short_value=Byte2 & Byte1. My camera send it like that... Byte[i+1] and Byte[i] make the intensity value I want...

Comment: This assumes that your buffer contains the bytes in little-endian order. According to the code example you provided they already are: You converted by using ((buffer[index + 1]) << 8) | (buffer[index]), so low byte first, high byte last.

Comment: Oh ok yeah that was a silly question. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

You could use the equivalent to the union of c. Im not sure if faster, but more elegant:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct byte_array
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte byte1;

  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte byte2;

  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public short int0;
}
```

use it like this:

```
byte_array ba = new byte_array();

//insert the two bytes
ba.byte1 = (byte)(buffer.Array[i]);
ba.byte2 = (byte)(buffer.Array[i + 1]);

//get the integer
NewImageVector[ImagePointer] = ba.int1;
```

You can fill your two bytes and use the int. To find the faster way take the StopWatch-Class and compare the two ways like this:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

//The code

stopWatch.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString()); //Or milliseconds ,...
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However my c# level is not very high so I am not sure how to use your suggestion :( Can you please give me more information on how to implement what you are suggesting? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this detailed example. I will try and let you know. :)

Comment: Ok so it turns out that in my machine my code runs in ~31ms and your code runs ~19ms. So you suggestion make it works much fatser. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a small performance increase by using unsafe pointers to iterate the arrays. The following code assumes that `source` is the input byte array (`buffer.Array` in your case). It also assumes that `source` has an even number of elements. In production code you would obviously have to check these things.

```
int[] output = new int[source.Length / 2];
fixed (byte* pSource = source)
fixed (int* pDestination = output)
{
    byte* sourceIterator = pSource;
    int* destIterator = pDestination;
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        (*destIterator) = ((*sourceIterator) | (*(sourceIterator + 1) << 8));
        destIterator++;
        sourceIterator += 2;
    }
}
return output;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this as well!!